# Trying to create a embedded web page on black berry and cannot set starting url

Tags: browser, blackberry

I’m trying to make an embedded web page on my blackberry app, and I'm having trouble setting the starting URL.

I can only set the URL when I do it from a callback from a `TextField`. When I try to do it after I push the new screen on, the app no longer works (it does nothing when you try to run it.

The code that works is the following:

```
protected boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time) 
{
    if ( key == Characters.ENTER ) 
    {
        Application.getApplication().invokeLater( new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() {                     
                    //progressBar.reset("", 0, 100, 0);
                    browserField.requestContent(locationBar.getText().trim());
                } 
            });
        return true;
    } 
    return super.keyChar(key, status, time);
}
```

When I try to set it automatically after everything is created, nothing happens when I run the app.

Code snippet

```
public MyApp() 
{
    pushScreen(new BrowserFieldScreen());

    // if I have this here, the app will not open
    Application.getApplication().invokeLater( new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() {                     
                gBrowserField.requestContent("http://google.com");
            } 
    });
}
```

The complete program:

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import net.rim.device.api.browser.field.ContentReadEvent;
import net.rim.device.api.browser.field2.BrowserField;
import net.rim.device.api.browser.field2.BrowserFieldListener;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Application;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Characters;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.GaugeField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.TextField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.BackgroundFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;  

/**
 * BrowserField2ProgressTracker
 * - A BrowserField2 Mini-browser application that keeps track of page-loading progress
 *   and displays progress information to the user.
 */

public class MyApp extends UiApplication {


    static BrowserField gBrowserField;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyApp theApp = new MyApp();
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    } 

    public MyApp() {
        pushScreen(new BrowserFieldScreen());
    /*  
        if I have this hear, the ap will not open
        Application.getApplication().invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {                     
                gBrowserField.requestContent("http://google.com");
            } 
        });
    }
    */
}

/**
 * BrowserFieldScreen
 * - A screen that contains a location bar, a progress bar, and a browser field
 */
class BrowserFieldScreen extends MainScreen {

    // The location bar where URL will be typed in
    private TextField locationBar;  


    // The BrowserField 
    private BrowserField browserField;


    public BrowserFieldScreen() {
//      progressTracker = new BrowserFieldLoadProgressTracker(10f);
        createGUI();


    }

    private void createGUI() {

        VerticalFieldManager mainManager = new VerticalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR | Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR );

        locationBar = new TextField() {

            protected boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time) {
                if ( key == Characters.ENTER ) {
                    Application.getApplication().invokeLater( new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {                     
                            //progressBar.reset("", 0, 100, 0);
                            browserField.requestContent(locationBar.getText().trim());
                        } 
                    });
                    return true;
                } 
                return super.keyChar(key, status, time);
            } 
        };

        locationBar.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.BEIGE));
        locationBar.setText("http://google.com");
        browserField = new BrowserField();

        MyApp.gBrowserField=browserField;
        mainManager.add(locationBar);
        mainManager.add(browserField);
        add(mainManager);   
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can call `invokeLater()` until your app, `theApp` has enter the main event thread. Which is done by calling `theApp.enterEventDispatcher()`

instead try changing your `BrowserFieldScreen` constructor to:

```
public BrowserFieldScreen() {
    //      progressTracker = new BrowserFieldLoadProgressTracker(10f);
    createGUI();
    browserField.requestContent("http://google.com");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it still does the same thing, it looks like i cant call requestcontent write away.  Do you know if the black berry has timer events? have any other idears? -Ted

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. It worked for me on a BB Torch. Are you running it on a device or simulator?

Comment: Hi,I'm running it on the simulater.  When I click on the apps icon in the simulater nothing happens, it does not crash just does nothing.

Comment: Just to be sure, does your `MyApp` constructor look like:          `public MyApp() {
        pushScreen(new BrowserFieldScreen());
    }`

Comment: Also in your debug or run configuration got to Simulator tab -> General and make sure you are not launching the app on start up. Then when the Simulator has finished booting up click the Status bar at the top to drop down some options. then setup a wifi network. then try running your app

Comment: Actually you can probably forget what i just said. Its seems to work for me if you check "Launch MDS-CS with simulator" in the General tab